# HybridAuth Facebook Web Log in fails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

I've enabled HybridAuth debug logger, deleted all previously existing hauth_log.txt files, and ran the FB login just once. Here are the contents of two debug files that HybridAuth simultaneously created:

#### File #1

```
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::initialize()
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). PHP version: 5.5.25
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth version: 2.4.1
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth called from: https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump used config:  -- a:8:{s:8:"base_url";s:100:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/";s:9:"providers";a:10:{s:6:"OpenID";a:1:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;}s:5:"Yahoo";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:3:"AOL";a:1:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;}s:6:"Google";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:72:"571789534893-6gkfplhm5h862nnl7v2g6s2qtt43o461.apps.googleusercontent.com";s:6:"secret";s:24:"fWroDRhs3nGYrOsMa5DXymsf";}}s:8:"Facebook";a:3:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:15:"981881825202878";s:6:"secret";s:32:"1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";}s:5:"scope";s:5:"email";}s:7:"Twitter";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:3:"key";s:25:"xXx87jlHmoV1WpIZfeZml5dgn";s:6:"secret";s:50:"0srvssRICN85tVuIuyuFHX0C5LZy8ByZZVFb9hbXjFHVEw7avP";}}s:4:"Live";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:7:"MySpace";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:8:"LinkedIn";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:10:"Foursquare";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}}s:10:"debug_mode";b:1;s:10:"debug_file";s:13:"hauth_log.txt";s:9:"path_base";s:124:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/";s:14:"path_libraries";s:135:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/";s:14:"path_resources";s:134:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/resources/";s:14:"path_providers";s:134:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/";}
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump current session:  -- a:1:{s:35:"hauth_session.facebook.is_logged_in";s:4:"i:0;";}
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: check if any error is stored on the endpoint...
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: no error found. initialization succeed.
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::authenticate( facebook )
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::authenticate( facebook ), User not connected to the provider. Try to authenticate..
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::setup( facebook ) -- 
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( facebook ), no params given. Trying to get the stored for this provider. -- 
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( facebook ), no stored params found for this provider. Initialize a new one for new session
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( facebook ). HybridAuth Callback URL set to:  -- https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::factory( facebook )
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Provider_Model::__construct( Facebook ) initialized. dump current adapter instance:  -- O:25:"Hybrid_Providers_Facebook":7:{s:5:"scope";s:112:"email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_website, read_stream, publish_actions, read_friendlists";s:10:"providerId";s:8:"Facebook";s:6:"config";a:3:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:15:"981881825202878";s:6:"secret";s:32:"1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";}s:5:"scope";s:5:"email";}s:6:"params";a:1:{s:15:"hauth_return_to";s:162:"https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813";}s:8:"endpoint";N;s:4:"user";O:11:"Hybrid_User":3:{s:10:"providerId";s:8:"Facebook";s:9:"timestamp";i:1444576222;s:7:"profile";O:19:"Hybrid_User_Profile":22:{s:10:"identifier";N;s:10:"webSiteURL";N;s:10:"profileURL";N;s:8:"photoURL";N;s:11:"displayName";N;s:11:"description";N;s:9:"firstName";N;s:8:"lastName";N;s:6:"gender";N;s:8:"language";N;s:3:"age";N;s:8:"birthDay";N;s:10:"birthMonth";N;s:9:"birthYear";N;s:5:"email";N;s:13:"emailVerified";N;s:5:"phone";N;s:7:"address";N;s:7:"country";N;s:6:"region";N;s:4:"city";N;s:3:"zip";N;}}s:3:"api";O:8:"Facebook":11:{s:18:" * sharedSessionID";N;s:11:" * response";N;s:8:" * appId";s:15:"981881825202878";s:12:" * appSecret";s:32:"1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";s:7:" * user";i:0;s:16:" * signedRequest";N;s:8:" * state";N;s:14:" * accessToken";s:48:"981881825202878|1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";s:20:" * fileUploadSupport";b:0;s:17:" * trustForwarded";b:0;s:21:" * allowSignedRequest";b:1;}}
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::login( Facebook ) 
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter [Facebook]::logout()
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::login( Facebook ), redirect the user to login_start URL. -- 
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::redirect( https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1444576222, PHP )
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:23+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::initialize()
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:23+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). PHP version: 5.5.25
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:23+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth version: 2.4.1
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:23+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth called from: https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:23+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump used config:  -- a:8:{s:8:"base_url";s:100:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/";s:9:"providers";a:10:{s:6:"OpenID";a:1:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;}s:5:"Yahoo";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:3:"AOL";a:1:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;}s:6:"Google";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:72:"571789534893-6gkfplhm5h862nnl7v2g6s2qtt43o461.apps.googleusercontent.com";s:6:"secret";s:24:"fWroDRhs3nGYrOsMa5DXymsf";}}s:8:"Facebook";a:3:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:15:"981881825202878";s:6:"secret";s:32:"1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";}s:5:"scope";s:5:"email";}s:7:"Twitter";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:3:"key";s:25:"xXx87jlHmoV1WpIZfeZml5dgn";s:6:"secret";s:50:"0srvssRICN85tVuIuyuFHX0C5LZy8ByZZVFb9hbXjFHVEw7avP";}}s:4:"Live";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:7:"MySpace";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:8:"LinkedIn";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:10:"Foursquare";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}}s:10:"debug_mode";b:1;s:10:"debug_file";s:13:"hauth_log.txt";s:9:"path_base";s:124:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/";s:14:"path_libraries";s:135:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/";s:14:"path_resources";s:134:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/resources/";s:14:"path_providers";s:134:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/";}
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:23+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump current session:  -- a:6:{s:26:"hauth_session.error.status";s:4:"i:1;";s:27:"hauth_session.error.message";s:68:"s:60:"Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id.";";s:24:"hauth_session.error.code";s:4:"i:5;";s:25:"hauth_session.error.trace";s:727:"s:718:"#0 /home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(182): Hybrid_Providers_Facebook->loginFinish()
#1 /home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(55): Hybrid_Endpoint->processAuthDone()
#2 /home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(71): Hybrid_Endpoint->__construct(NULL)
#3 /home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/index.php(15): Hybrid_Endpoint::process()
#4 {main}";";s:28:"hauth_session.error.previous";s:2:"N;";s:35:"hauth_session.facebook.is_logged_in";s:4:"i:0;";}
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:23+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: check if any error is stored on the endpoint...
ERROR -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:23+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: A stored Error found, Throw an new Exception and delete it from the store: Error#5, 'Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id.' -- 
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:23+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Error::clearError()
```

[(Pastebin version)](http://pastebin.com/AAvVyGkC)

#### File #2

```
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::initialize()
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). PHP version: 5.5.25
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth version: 2.4.1
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth called from: https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1444576222
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump used config:  -- a:8:{s:8:"base_url";s:100:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/";s:9:"providers";a:10:{s:6:"OpenID";a:1:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;}s:5:"Yahoo";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:3:"AOL";a:1:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;}s:6:"Google";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:72:"571789534893-6gkfplhm5h862nnl7v2g6s2qtt43o461.apps.googleusercontent.com";s:6:"secret";s:24:"fWroDRhs3nGYrOsMa5DXymsf";}}s:8:"Facebook";a:3:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:15:"981881825202878";s:6:"secret";s:32:"1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";}s:5:"scope";s:5:"email";}s:7:"Twitter";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:3:"key";s:25:"xXx87jlHmoV1WpIZfeZml5dgn";s:6:"secret";s:50:"0srvssRICN85tVuIuyuFHX0C5LZy8ByZZVFb9hbXjFHVEw7avP";}}s:4:"Live";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:7:"MySpace";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:8:"LinkedIn";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:10:"Foursquare";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}}s:10:"debug_mode";b:1;s:10:"debug_file";s:13:"hauth_log.txt";s:9:"path_base";s:124:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/";s:14:"path_libraries";s:135:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/";s:14:"path_resources";s:134:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/resources/";s:14:"path_providers";s:134:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/";}
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump current session:  -- a:3:{s:38:"hauth_session.facebook.hauth_return_to";s:171:"s:162:"https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813";";s:37:"hauth_session.facebook.hauth_endpoint";s:129:"s:120:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook";";s:41:"hauth_session.facebook.id_provider_params";s:602:"a:5:{s:15:"hauth_return_to";s:162:"https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813";s:11:"hauth_token";s:26:"s22d91qp2344j689rpncndobb7";s:10:"hauth_time";i:1444576222;s:11:"login_start";s:143:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1444576222";s:10:"login_done";s:120:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook";}";}
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: check if any error is stored on the endpoint...
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: no error found. initialization succeed.
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::setup( Facebook ) -- 
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Facebook ), no params given. Trying to get the stored for this provider. -- Array
(
    [hauth_return_to] => https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813
    [hauth_token] => s22d91qp2344j689rpncndobb7
    [hauth_time] => 1444576222
    [login_start] => https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1444576222
    [login_done] => https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook
)

INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::factory( Facebook )
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Provider_Model::__construct( Facebook ) initialized. dump current adapter instance:  -- O:25:"Hybrid_Providers_Facebook":7:{s:5:"scope";s:112:"email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_website, read_stream, publish_actions, read_friendlists";s:10:"providerId";s:8:"Facebook";s:6:"config";a:3:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:15:"981881825202878";s:6:"secret";s:32:"1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";}s:5:"scope";s:5:"email";}s:6:"params";a:5:{s:15:"hauth_return_to";s:162:"https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813";s:11:"hauth_token";s:26:"s22d91qp2344j689rpncndobb7";s:10:"hauth_time";i:1444576222;s:11:"login_start";s:143:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1444576222";s:10:"login_done";s:120:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook";}s:8:"endpoint";s:120:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook";s:4:"user";O:11:"Hybrid_User":3:{s:10:"providerId";s:8:"Facebook";s:9:"timestamp";i:1444576222;s:7:"profile";O:19:"Hybrid_User_Profile":22:{s:10:"identifier";N;s:10:"webSiteURL";N;s:10:"profileURL";N;s:8:"photoURL";N;s:11:"displayName";N;s:11:"description";N;s:9:"firstName";N;s:8:"lastName";N;s:6:"gender";N;s:8:"language";N;s:3:"age";N;s:8:"birthDay";N;s:10:"birthMonth";N;s:9:"birthYear";N;s:5:"email";N;s:13:"emailVerified";N;s:5:"phone";N;s:7:"address";N;s:7:"country";N;s:6:"region";N;s:4:"city";N;s:3:"zip";N;}}s:3:"api";O:8:"Facebook":11:{s:18:" * sharedSessionID";N;s:11:" * response";N;s:8:" * appId";s:15:"981881825202878";s:12:" * appSecret";s:32:"1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";s:7:" * user";i:0;s:16:" * signedRequest";N;s:8:" * state";N;s:14:" * accessToken";s:48:"981881825202878|1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";s:20:" * fileUploadSupport";b:0;s:17:" * trustForwarded";b:0;s:21:" * allowSignedRequest";b:1;}}
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Endpoint: call adapter [Facebook] loginBegin()
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::redirect( https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=981881825202878&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fidiabox.com%2Fcodecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system%2Fvendor%2Fhybridauth%2F%3Fhauth.done%3DFacebook&state=418b60768df976777e623a1fdb3c9430&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3&scope=email&display=page, PHP )
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::initialize()
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). PHP version: 5.5.25
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth version: 2.4.1
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth called from: https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook&code=AQCMsPSqGqg7XxNeYhEC8h_wWzSEgJQ0c5iCZzHcbqsr6UmZBYaADFfZRWACKeD41F0bYsjCFd74Gyw1c3x4LyTWDkE54CG0u5wsVhOlDkh82rMOAcywLjdakPxJ1_H8IvARxiOYzG-1_t8d9bE6I9kYuvWeHNwK8damU6xBC57O_GUxGFJwkYsukPzusREoFqOnSfDixazkHEYHWqca5wD3rvpw9dNnJJzS5hLOE0h5InrPItzvWNQ2gTldUHp7pXjwLhv88ARSG8wBncnpCfLSWw9YT2cYMqGKkWhA5Aj2y80PDKVMfgeGgcL5Jr87LBI&state=418b60768df976777e623a1fdb3c9430
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump used config:  -- a:8:{s:8:"base_url";s:100:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/";s:9:"providers";a:10:{s:6:"OpenID";a:1:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;}s:5:"Yahoo";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:3:"AOL";a:1:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;}s:6:"Google";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:72:"571789534893-6gkfplhm5h862nnl7v2g6s2qtt43o461.apps.googleusercontent.com";s:6:"secret";s:24:"fWroDRhs3nGYrOsMa5DXymsf";}}s:8:"Facebook";a:3:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:15:"981881825202878";s:6:"secret";s:32:"1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";}s:5:"scope";s:5:"email";}s:7:"Twitter";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:3:"key";s:25:"xXx87jlHmoV1WpIZfeZml5dgn";s:6:"secret";s:50:"0srvssRICN85tVuIuyuFHX0C5LZy8ByZZVFb9hbXjFHVEw7avP";}}s:4:"Live";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:7:"MySpace";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:8:"LinkedIn";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:3:"key";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}s:10:"Foursquare";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:0;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:0:"";s:6:"secret";s:0:"";}}}s:10:"debug_mode";b:1;s:10:"debug_file";s:13:"hauth_log.txt";s:9:"path_base";s:124:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/";s:14:"path_libraries";s:135:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/";s:14:"path_resources";s:134:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/resources/";s:14:"path_providers";s:134:"/home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/";}
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump current session:  -- a:3:{s:38:"hauth_session.facebook.hauth_return_to";s:171:"s:162:"https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813";";s:37:"hauth_session.facebook.hauth_endpoint";s:129:"s:120:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook";";s:41:"hauth_session.facebook.id_provider_params";s:602:"a:5:{s:15:"hauth_return_to";s:162:"https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813";s:11:"hauth_token";s:26:"s22d91qp2344j689rpncndobb7";s:10:"hauth_time";i:1444576222;s:11:"login_start";s:143:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1444576222";s:10:"login_done";s:120:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook";}";}
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: check if any error is stored on the endpoint...
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: no error found. initialization succeed.
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::setup( Facebook ) -- 
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Facebook ), no params given. Trying to get the stored for this provider. -- Array
(
    [hauth_return_to] => https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813
    [hauth_token] => s22d91qp2344j689rpncndobb7
    [hauth_time] => 1444576222
    [login_start] => https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1444576222
    [login_done] => https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook
)

INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::factory( Facebook )
DEBUG -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Hybrid_Provider_Model::__construct( Facebook ) initialized. dump current adapter instance:  -- O:25:"Hybrid_Providers_Facebook":7:{s:5:"scope";s:112:"email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_website, read_stream, publish_actions, read_friendlists";s:10:"providerId";s:8:"Facebook";s:6:"config";a:3:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:15:"981881825202878";s:6:"secret";s:32:"1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";}s:5:"scope";s:5:"email";}s:6:"params";a:5:{s:15:"hauth_return_to";s:162:"https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813";s:11:"hauth_token";s:26:"s22d91qp2344j689rpncndobb7";s:10:"hauth_time";i:1444576222;s:11:"login_start";s:143:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1444576222";s:10:"login_done";s:120:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook";}s:8:"endpoint";s:120:"https://idiabox.com/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Facebook";s:4:"user";O:11:"Hybrid_User":3:{s:10:"providerId";s:8:"Facebook";s:9:"timestamp";i:1444576222;s:7:"profile";O:19:"Hybrid_User_Profile":22:{s:10:"identifier";N;s:10:"webSiteURL";N;s:10:"profileURL";N;s:8:"photoURL";N;s:11:"displayName";N;s:11:"description";N;s:9:"firstName";N;s:8:"lastName";N;s:6:"gender";N;s:8:"language";N;s:3:"age";N;s:8:"birthDay";N;s:10:"birthMonth";N;s:9:"birthYear";N;s:5:"email";N;s:13:"emailVerified";N;s:5:"phone";N;s:7:"address";N;s:7:"country";N;s:6:"region";N;s:4:"city";N;s:3:"zip";N;}}s:3:"api";O:8:"Facebook":11:{s:18:" * sharedSessionID";N;s:11:" * response";N;s:8:" * appId";s:15:"981881825202878";s:12:" * appSecret";s:32:"1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";s:7:" * user";i:0;s:16:" * signedRequest";N;s:8:" * state";N;s:14:" * accessToken";s:48:"981881825202878|1a1db36c322f40166ec845be31c4782d";s:20:" * fileUploadSupport";b:0;s:17:" * trustForwarded";b:0;s:21:" * allowSignedRequest";b:1;}}
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Endpoint: call adapter [Facebook] loginFinish() 
ERROR -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Exception:Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id. -- Exception Object
(
    [message:protected] => Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id.
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 5
    [file:protected] => /home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Facebook.php
    [line:protected] => 139
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php
                    [line] => 182
                    [function] => loginFinish
                    [class] => Hybrid_Providers_Facebook
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php
                    [line] => 55
                    [function] => processAuthDone
                    [class] => Hybrid_Endpoint
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php
                    [line] => 71
                    [function] => __construct
                    [class] => Hybrid_Endpoint
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/ninoskopac/public_html/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/vendor/hybridauth/index.php
                    [line] => 15
                    [function] => process
                    [class] => Hybrid_Endpoint
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)

INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Error::setError( Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id. )
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter [Facebook]::setUserUnconnected()
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Endpoint: job done. retrun to callback url.
INFO -- 141.101.93.135 -- 2015-10-11T23:10:22+08:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::redirect( https://idiabox.com/idiabox/codecanyon-5282621-advanced-security-php-registerlogin-system/socialauth.php?p=facebook&token=EVRSzGASrYxEVyA9vi3uIuwx3QLq0E4FzVy9C813, PHP )
```

[(Pastebin version)](http://pastebin.com/Ws4gJRFu)

Comment: Main error message seems to be "Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id.". I realized I may have left API secrets inside the logs, but I'm gonna reset them on FB dashboard now anyway. <-- saying this via comment cause I've exceeded 30k chars limit

Comment: What the version sdk do you use? May be it related with this fixed issues https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/pull/41 https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/pull/70

Comment: Hi @alexs. I just updated the FB sdk (these files specifically: https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/blob/master/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Facebook.php, https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/blob/master/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/Facebook/facebook.php, https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/blob/master/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/Facebook/base_facebook.php) and it didn't help.
Here's more debug data: https://gist.github.com/NinoSkopac/3daf7dba59cca6eaf3dd#file-hybridauth-facebook-var_dump-get_defined_vars-hybrid_auth-logger-hybrid_auth-error

Comment: Try the following suggestions http://w3guy.com/authentication-failed-facebook-returned-invalid-user-id/

Comment: @alexs Hi again. I've already followed that article a couple of days back, and it didn't help me. But, *I've solved the issue*, by changing scope from "email" to "email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown" (as in the article). Feel free to post a real answer so I can accept & upvote it (you deserve the credit). Also, if you found this question via Upwork, please contact me there so I can award you there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the scope in Facebook config file to "email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown".